# Web Push Notification Error

Tags: javascript, push-notification

I am currently developing a Progressive Web App, a Messanger.
I'm trying to implement Web Push notifications, but get an error:

```
Error: The subscription p256dh value should be 65 bytes long.
    at Object.encrypt (script.js:67350)
    at Object.WebPushLib.generateRequestDetails (script.js:67851)
    at Object.WebPushLib.sendNotification (script.js:67921)
    at script.js:427
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (script.js:418)
    at fire (script.js:57068)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (script.js:57198)
    at done (script.js:63023)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (script.js:63265)
```

Unfortunately I can not find a solution for this problem on the internet.

Here I offer notifications, subscribe a user to Notifications and save this subscription to mongodb.

```
function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
            const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
            const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');

            const rawData = window.atob(base64);
            const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
                outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return outputArray;
        }

    function offerNotification() {
        if ("Notification" in window && "PushManager" in window && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission){
                if (permission === "granted") {
                    var subscribeOptions = {
                        userVisibleOnly: true,
                        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(
                            "BFj8CT2z3z40tC-qDDVBj4EnhV345Bx53H_cYkF92w89_7G1dG8Gv4G0FhEACXSFOKf3gvC0eu0VbRRk1pSRpWU"
                        )
                    };
                    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
                        return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
                    }).then(function(subscription) {
                        var fetchOptions = {
                            method: "post",
                            headers: new Headers({
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            }),
                            body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
                        };
                        return fetch("/add-subscription/", fetchOptions);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

subscriptions.js

```
var webpush = require("web-push");

/**
 * Sends a push message to all subscriptions
 */

function notify(pushPayload) {
    var pushKeys;
    $.getJSON("/pushkeys/", function (data) {
        pushKeys = data;
        pushPayload = JSON.stringify(pushPayload);
        webpush.setGCMAPIKey(pushKeys[0].GCMAPIKey);
        webpush.setVapidDetails(
            pushKeys[0].subject,
            pushKeys[0].publicKey,
            pushKeys[0].privateKey
        );

        $.getJSON("/subscriptions/", function (subscriptions) {
            subscriptions.forEach(function(subscription) {
                webpush
                    .sendNotification(subscription, pushPayload)
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log("Notification sent");
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log(err);

                        console.log("Notification failed");
                    });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

when a new user registers, all other users are notified.

```
 notify({
      type: "user-registration",
      user: user
 });
```

and listener in Serviceworker

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) { console.log("hier");
    var data = event.data.json(); console.log(data);
    if (data.type === "user-registration") {
        var user = data.user;
        event.waitUntil(
            self.registration.showNotification("Neur Nutzer :", {
                body: user.nickname + " hat sich registriert.",
                icon: "/images/icons/icon-64x64.png",
                tag: "user-registration",
                vibrate: [500,110,500,110,450,110,200,110,170,40,450,110,200,110]
            })

        );
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be a very stupid question. Did you try passing the Base64 value as such instead of the array buffer? The MDN Doc says you can pass either one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe#Syntax

Comment: I get the following error when I try it as you have suggested: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'

Comment: I recently encountered this error while testing on my device, though it was working fine earlier. I checked p256 value, (BIv PQi8CM-BK-JuFRDkPh2T0oRpEel2vwLOVD) which looked different from previous values and smaller string with an space. I again subscribed with the same device, and this time got correct type value. And it started working and notification got sent successfully. May be you can check your p256dh value, and also check if correct value is being received by server as sent by client.